# Weblogic 11g in AWS - Cannot access Admin server behind ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, weblogic, amazon-elb

I have set up Weblogic 11g on Linux in AWS and configured the admin server and a generic domain. I have configured the admin server to listen on port 7001 for all addresses (0.0.0.0).

When I browse to the url of the instance directly (http://x.x.x.x:7001/console) I can access the admin server as expected. However, when I add the instance to a load balancer and try to access the admin console through the elb (http://amazon_elb_a_name/console) I get a blank page. No error displayed, but also no content. I've checked the server logs and WL logs, but nothing jumps out at me. I have configure the elb to listen on port 80 and forward to the instance on 7001. The instance and ELB are in the same subnet on the same VPC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you configured the elb health check ? Is the elb instance status "InService" ?

Comment: Hi Asanka - I discovered what was going on. I had the health check configured, but it was failing. I wasn't sure why. After running a curl to the login page I was getting a 302 code returned (redirect). When I configured the health check to use the redirect URL everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what was going on. I had the health check configured, but it was failing. After running a curl to the login page I was getting a 302 code returned (redirect). When I configured the health check to use the redirect URL everything worked as expected